# SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111 With Spring SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbctemplate

Hi All I am using spring simple JDBC template to call the oracle procedure the below are my code.

The procedure

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_all_system_users(
pi_client_code IN VARCHAR2,
po_system_users OUT T_SYSTEM_USER_TAB,
po_error_code        OUT NUMBER,
po_error_description OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
ctr NUMBER;
sysUser SYSTEM_USER_OBJ;
BEGIN
ctr:=0;
po_system_users:= t_system_user_tab();
end
```

The Spring Dao class

```
public class ManualSaleStoredProcedureDao {

private SimpleJdbcCall getAllSytemUsers;

public List<SystemUser> getAllSytemUsers(String clientCode) {

    MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    in.addValue("pi_client_code", clientCode);
    in.addValue("po_system_users", null,
            OracleTypes.ARRAY, "T_SYSTEM_USER_TAB");

    Map<String, Object> result = getAllSytemUsers.execute(in);

    return null;

}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

    getAllSytemUsers = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("SChemaName")
            .withProcedureName("get_all_system_users")

            .declareParameters(

                    new SqlParameter(
                            "pi_client_code",
                            OracleTypes.VARCHAR,
                            "pi_client_code"));

}
```

When I am calling `Map<String, Object> result = getAllSytemUsers.execute(in);`
Iam getting the below exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call VSC.GET_ALL_SYSTEM_USERS(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:351)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:181)
at com.budco.vsc.dao.ManualSaleStoredProcedureDao.getAllSytemUsers(ManualSaleStoredProcedureDao.java:30)
at com.budco.vsc.dao.ManualSaleStoredProcedureDaoITest.getCustomerNotes(ManualSaleStoredProcedureDaoITest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3950)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:135)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:304)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:393)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1569)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:95)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1008)
... 35 more
```

Comment: check if this helps http://www.coderanch.com/t/489862/Spring/Calling-Stored-Procedure-Spring-StoredProcedure .Did you try calling the procedure in sql prompt ? Did it work ?

Comment: There is no error in the procedure it working fine, The error might in java side.

Comment: It worked for me only use CallableStatement. It is strange that in other similar procedures there are no problems.

Comment: If you use IN clause in sql query, then you can't pass list of values in place of this directly it need to converted to comma separated strings or need to be handled smartly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve the issues using below code. This type of error will happen when there is a mismatch between In/Out parameter as declare in procedure and in java code `declareParameters`. Here we need to defined oracle return tab

```
public class ManualSaleStoredProcedureDao {

private SimpleJdbcCall getAllSytemUsers;

public List<SystemUser> getAllSytemUsers(String clientCode) {

    MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    in.addValue("pi_client_code", clientCode);
    Map<String, Object> result = getAllSytemUsers.execute(in);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<SystemUser> systemUsers = (List<SystemUser>) result
            .get(VSCConstants.GET_SYSTEM_USER_OUT_PARAM1);
    return systemUsers;

}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

    getAllSytemUsers = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName(VSCConstants.SCHEMA)
            .withProcedureName(VSCConstants.GET_SYSTEM_USER_PROC_NAME)
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter(
                            "pi_client_code",
                            OracleTypes.NUMBER,
                            "pi_client_code"),
                    new SqlInOutParameter(
                            "po_system_users",
                            OracleTypes.ARRAY,
                            "T_SYSTEM_USER_TAB",
                            new OracleSystemUser()));

}
```

Comment: Why do you not include how you solved it instead of pasting code?

Comment: Please see the edits, The error will happen due to mismatch of IN/OUT parameter as declare in procedure and java code

Comment: hey I don't know if you still have the code but can you show me the code of OracleSystemUser() class

Comment: Sorry Bro, I do not have the code with me now

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is with the datatype of the data you are passing `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111` check the datatypes you pass with the actual column datatypes may be there can be some mismatch or some constraint violation with `null`

Comment: sometimes it could be enum type value that interferes with data type.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to insert schema identifier here:

```
in.addValue("po_system_users", null, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "your_schema.T_SYSTEM_USER_TAB");
```

Comment: @KrushnaCh.Dash - Are parameters for `new SqlParameter()` correct?

Comment: Yes adding SQL parameter is optional as i have mention the type at the top

Answer (score 1):

I have a function which returns a CLOB and I was seeing the above error when I'd forgotten to declare the return value as an output parameter.  Initially I had:

```
protected SimpleJdbcCall buildJdbcCall(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate)
{
    SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withSchemaName(schema)
        .withCatalogName(catalog)
        .withFunctionName(functionName)
        .withReturnValue()          
        .declareParameters(buildSqlParameters());

    return call;
}

public SqlParameter[] buildSqlParameters() {
    return new SqlParameter[]{
        new SqlParameter("p_names", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_format", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_units", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_datums", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_start", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_end", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_timezone", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_office_id", Types.VARCHAR),
        };
}
```

The buildSqlParameters method should have included the SqlOutParameter:

```
public SqlParameter[] buildSqlParameters() {
    return new SqlParameter[]{
        new SqlParameter("p_names", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_format", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_units", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_datums", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_start", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_end", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_timezone", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlParameter("p_office_id", Types.VARCHAR),
        new SqlOutParameter("l_clob", Types.CLOB)  // <-- This was missing!
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue when we had a typo in the mybatis mapping file like

```
        ....
        #{column1Name,          jdbcType=INTEGER},
        #{column2Name,          jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{column3Name,      jdbcTyep=VARCHAR}  -- do you see the typo ?
        .....
```

So check this kind of typos as well. Unfortunately, it can not understand the typo in compile/build time, it causes an unchecked exception and booms in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and turns out the problem was that I had used

```java
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withProcedureName("foo")
```

instead of

```java
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withFunctionName("foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The cause was a table of record indexed type.

This

```
TYPE tp_tb IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(21) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Instead of

```
TYPE tp_tb IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(21);
```